Is there a way to connect Xiaomi watch in Android Studio? or is there any existing library?
Is there a way to connect Xiaomi watch in Android Studio? or is there any existing library?
I'm trying to connect my Watch in Android Studio and try to customize it

If that watch does not feature an USB port, one can only use BT or WiFi.
Also on WearOS, one first has to enable developer mode (else there's nothing to connect to). Then one has to pair the device. And finally, one can connect the ADB debug bridge.
https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/get-started/debugging#enable-dev-options
But you'll likely not customize much by doing so, because this is not how to bake custom WearOS system ROM. This ADB connection is only meant for for app development and app debugging.
